# Need opinion for an interface

Tags: usability, usability-testing

I need an opinion on for my app [checkux](http://jaydeepgajera.com/checkux/):

> 1. Should I use green background on checked state of the checkbox or not?
> 2. Where should I place the Progress bar which is on top(currently).

Comment: Hi Panqjin, not sure this is a good fit for Q&A, in its current state it primarily promotes answers based on personal preference. One comment I have however is that you should add padding to the panels, right now the checkbox touches the bezel of the panels on hover and focus. I think the placement of the progress bar is good, but it could be a bit more subtle (not so "in your face"). I would experiment with adjusting the font-color rather than changing background. Start out with a lighter grey and on hover/focus I would switch to the black font. Right now it gets cluttered and obstructive

Comment: Agree with @AndroidHustle about the padding. I'm also wondering what the point of the progress bar is. Does it get to 100% if I check everything? Why would I do all this checking - esp if the element in question isn't on my page (EG sounds or video)?

Comment: Thanx I got your points.
I too agree with you guys and I will make changes.
and Yes progress bar get 100% after you check all of them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requesting a review of a website. Such questions will only benefit the question-asker themselves and not any other visitors to this site.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. Add some clue that the progress bar is in fact a progress bar (eg show "0% progress" by default) because I didn't recognize until I clicked an item.
2. Move the progress bar below the "Usability Checklist" heading because the progress bar 'belongs' to the items below the heading. Again it's not immediately clear that the progress bar is a progress bar to me.
3. Highlight the background of checklist items; the border is not obvious enough.
4. Make the progress bar the same width as the copy container
5. Make sure that the page is not too wide at large resolutions (I have 1600x900 and it's too wide for my liking). Always remember that people can only read an area of like one inch across at any time, so moving your eyes more than a couple of inches from the center can be taxing.

Again, those are my suggestions even they're written more like commands.